# VBA to compare rows in two different sheets and if they match highlight in red

Tags: vba, excel

I have been searching online and cannot seem to find much help around what I'm trying to do.

I'm looking to compare two sheets in one workbook. For example, if sheet 1 row 1 matches a row in sheet 2 then highlight it red if not leave blank. I tried:

```
Sub Test_Sheet()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As Range
    Set s = Sheets("Already Billed").Columns(1)

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows
        If Not (s.Find(r.Cells(1,1).Value)Is Nothing) Then
            r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

But if I change the data in column 3 it does not register as the above is only looking in column 1 but I need the whole row to be check.

Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: How many columns you need to check? And why not to use Conditional Formatting for this?

Comment: You do realize you have `Set s = Sheets("Already Billed").Columns(1)`? If you want to extend your search to your whole used range than something like : `Set s = Sheets("Already Billed").UsedRange` would work. If it's just a few columns you need to check than: `Set s = Sheets("Already Billed").Columns("A:C")` would do.

Comment: @JvdV i tried both methods and i got the same results. there is one difference in column 4 where one row does not contain a date so it shouldn't be highlighted but it is. is the code above actually comparing sheet 1 to the rows in sheet 2? sorry i didn't realise my mistake (new to VBA).

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns this would be formula based correct? is there a formula that allows you to compare one sheet to another across multiple columns? thanks!

Comment: That's why I'm asking you how many columns. You could concatenate several IFS and use Conditional Formatting, but I recommend this if you have a few columns. If you are working on data around 200 columns, then I don't

Comment: Thanks @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns